# error on removing an object in list in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, web-applications

I'm deploying a client app with vue.js.
In this app I have some tabs that are being rendered using v-for. this tab array is formated like this in vuex store:

```
tabs: [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: 'first tab',
    number: '09389826331',
    accountName: 'DelirCo',
    contactName: 'PourTabarestani',
    startTime: '2019-02-25 15:11:30',
    endTime: '2019-02-25 18:04:10',
    duration: null,
    subject: '',
    description: ''
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: 'second tab',
    number: '09124578986',
    accountName: 'Cisco',
    accountGUID: '',
    contactName: 'Arcada',
    contactGUID: '',
    startTime: '2019-02-25 15:11:45',
    endTime: '2019-02-25 15:13:55',
    duration: null,
    subject: '',
    description: ''
  }
]
```

I'm using getters to load the tabs in my vuex store which renders the tabs using following template:

```
<template>
  <div id="Tabs">
    <vs-tabs color="#17a2b8" v-model="selectedTab">
      <vs-tab v-for="tab in tabs" :key="tab.id" :vs- 
        label="tab.title">
        <Tab :tab="tab"></Tab>
      </vs-tab>
    </vs-tabs>
  </div>
</template>
```

I'm using vuesax components for creating the tabs displays.
each object in this list is a tab in my front end which shows the related data when I click each tab.
it's doing perfectly fine when I try to show the tabs or even adding another object in the array. 
the problem is when I try to remove a certain item from this array the content goes away but the tab title (the button where I can select the tab with it) remains on the page.
I'm using

```
state.tabs.splice(objectIndex, 1)
state.selectedTab -= 1
```

for removing the tab and changing the selected tab to the previous one.
but as I said the title of the tab is not being removed like the picture below:

[image: picture]
and when I click on that tab I'm getting this error:

```
webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vuesax/dist/vuesax.common.js:4408 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'invert' of undefined
at VueComponent.activeChild (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vuesax/dist/vuesax.common.js:4408)
at click (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vuesax/dist/vuesax.common.js:4127)
at invoker (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vue/dist/vue.esm.js:2140)
at HTMLButtonElement.fn._withTask.fn._withTask (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vue/dist/vue.esm.js:1925)
```

anyone have any suggestion around this matter ?

Comment: Can you show us how you're rendering the tabs?

Comment: I've added my dashboard component where I render the tabs in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be an issue with the [vuesax](https://github.com/lusaxweb/vuesax) library. The `<vs-tabs>` component doesn't support `<vs-tab>` components being added/removed as child components dynamically.

Here's an excerpt from the [vsTab.vue](https://github.com/lusaxweb/vuesax/blob/413627d939a8df2df56a68cbc70e4f7d70a7acb8/src/components/vsTabs/vsTab.vue) file in the repo:

```es6
mounted(){
  this.id = this.$parent.children.length
  this.$parent.children.push({
    label: this.vsLabel,
    icon: this.vsIcon,
    id: this.$parent.children.length,
    listeners: this.$listeners,
    attrs: this.$attrs
  })
}
```

When the `<vs-tab>` component is mounted, it adds itself to the parent (`<vs-tabs>`) as a child, but it does not remove itself from this array when it is destroyed.

You can open an issue on their GitHub page to see if they could support what you want, or you can submit a pull request.

Comment: Thanks mate. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

You can just add a key to the parent element to force the rerender.

```
<div :key="forceRender">
    <vs-tabs :value="activeTab">
      <template v-for="item in items">
        <vs-tab :label="item.name" @click="onTabChange(item)">
          <div class="con-tab-ejemplo">
            <slot name="content"></slot>
          </div>
        </vs-tab>
      </template>
    </vs-tabs>
  </div>
```

After that add a watcher on the `items`:

```
watch: {
  items (val) {
    this.forceRender += 1
  }
},
```

Comment: Can't believe i had to do that.